# Should I put how many years of experience I have in my resume summary or will that make human resources disinterested?

Tags: resume, hiring-process

Currently in my resume I have "Full Stack Developer with a 1.5 year track record of writing maintainable, and efficient code while working with developer teams and clients" and I think this is an accurate way to summarize my self.

However when speaking to recruiters over the phone or through Linkedin, I often find if I tell them straight off the bat that I only have 1.5 years of experience they almost immediately tell me they need someone with more experience and that is the end of the conversion, but if I don't tell them that and just talk about my past experiences instead they will cater the conversation and move me through to interviews.

Should I include that description in my resume or will this make hr people disinterested immediately?

Comment: I'm confused - I'm assuming your dates are on your resume too. So are you hoping to find an HR department that can't subtract?

Comment: Yes, dates are on my resume. It's just that when I speak to HR people through linkedin/phone calls and tell them upfront that I have 1.5 years of experience the conversation is quickly proceeded by "we're looking for someone with more experience" vs if they figure it out themselves after I've talked to them about my experience they might say "well we usually take people with three or more years but for this case I think bla bla bla"

Comment: It's far better to be rejected early, so you can spend your time on potential jobs that are a good match.  There *are* companies looking for junior-level developers.

Comment: "writing maintainable, and efficient code" should be left out. This is expected of a professional developer; not something that should be seen as something special that needs mentioning.

Comment: Think of your resume as a sales brochure highlighting the best reasons why a recruiter should call you in for an interview. Do you consider having 1.5 years experience a selling point that should be highlighted?

Answer (score 8):

I think your own experience has provided you with an answer. Not mentioning your short time in the field of work while speaking on the topic in that field has proven more fruitful for you thus far. You should probably stick with that.

Any resume I am familiar with will have start/end dates of each job you have held so HR and any person reviewing your resume will probably notice the time frame.

That being said if you can prove your knowledge during a phone conversation or an in-person interview, there is no real reason to mention the length of time you have worked in that field unless someone ask you directly about it.

Just do your best to accurately answer any technical questions and be a likable candidate and many people will overlook your time in the field if you can prove your worth up front.

Some interviewers are very set in stone about the required years of work in the field for various reason. Best coarse of action is to answer any questions and do not mention your 1.5 years of work unless directly asked.

If you are asked about it be confident and don't hesitate to answer. Same goes for any question you are asked.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, the person writing the job description is not the person reading the resume. In terms of organizing your resume, you already have experienced ageism based on your lack of years as a developer, so you should focus on things that do not change such as your completed projects. Moreover, as a developer, you can demonstrate evidence of your qualifications via apps or websites you've created by yourself, participation on stackoverflow or other stackexchange sites, articles you've published, or videos you've posted on your experience.

**References**

- [Jison: Build parsers in JavaScript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jison-build-parsers-in-javascript)
- [Progression, Curiosity, and Burnout with Dan Abramov](https://tylermcginnis.com/podcast/dan-abramov/)
- [Profile John Resig Origins of the JavaScript ninja](https://xrds.acm.org/article.cfm?aid=1836557)